# Unable to append rules in iptable in docker

Tags: docker, containers, firewall, iptables, rules

I am trying to add a rule which looks like:

```
Chain DOCKER (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.8           tcp dpt:21102
```

I am using the following command:

```
sudo iptables -A DOCKER -t tcp -s anywhere -d 172.18.0.8 --dport 21102 -j ACCEPT
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
table 'tcp' does not exist
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Can someone please guide me where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-t` : Specifies the packet matching table such as nat, filter, raw.etc

`-p` : Sets the IP protocol for the rule, which can be either icmp, tcp, udp, or all.

So the command should be:

```
sudo iptables -A DOCKER -p tcp -s {source_ip} -d 172.18.0.8 --dport 21102 -j ACCEPT
```